# How to get remote username on windows machine

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop

I tried this command `wmic.exe /node:IP-or-HostName ComputerSystem Get UserName` but I get **access denied** as i don't have password to the remote machine.I can only ping the ipaddress and I have its name `xxx.yyy.com` Is it possible to get username or any more details about remote machine without having a login access to it.

Comment: absolutely not, and if you could that would be a serious security hole, which I would expect them to patch immediately. you can probably find other mechanisms (sniff some of their network traffic, etc), but not from WMI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the name of a user that is currently logged into a PC in your network with PowerShell (ExecutionPolicy needs to be set to RemoteSigned on the target PC)

```
get-wmiobject -class win32_computersystem <IP> | format-list UserName, Name
```

But it looks like you want to do that with a web server. If the Admin of that server did his job well, you will not be able to find out which account is currently logged into it.